# FirstOrDefault two ways

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I can not understand the difference between these two ways of setting FirstOrDefault:

```
Product a = (from r in _context.Products where r.IDPROD.Equals(10) select r).FirstOrDefault();
Product a = (from s in _context.Products where s.IDPROD == 10 select s).FirstOrDefault<Products>();
```

Someone could explain me in a simple way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
where r.IDPROD.Equals(10) select r).FirstOrDefault();
```

Method [Int32.Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf6tw08e.aspx) used. Then `FirstOrdefault<T>` where `T` is detected by compiler automatically (it will be type of `r`).

```
where s.IDPROD == 10 select s).FirstOrDefault<Products>()
```

Operator `==` overloading used instead. Result forcefully casted to `Products`.

---

I would write this using Extension Method syntax:

```
Product p = _context.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IDPROD == 10);
```

don't mix it with Query Syntax.

Comment: There's no "forceful cast". I take it that `_context.Products` is `IEnumerable<Products>`. Then `s` will be a `Products` already, and the `from ... select` query is `IEnumerable<Products>` as well. Then the extension method `FirstOrDefault<Products>` is applied. No cast. In the first example, also `FirstOrDefault<Products>` is applied, only here the type `Products` is _inferred_ by the compiler by ***type inference***. So no cast here. We have some information that is optional to supply because the compiler can figure it out by itself. (Similarly with `IQueryable<>` of course.)

Answer (score 3):

It is the same. The first version is FirstOrDefault with inferred generic parameter.